# App Pool Identity and PDF generation issues

Tags: pdf, iis, identity

I have an ASP.NET website running on a Windows 2012 server. This website is using an application pool whose identity was a Custom account which is an Active Directory account.

This morning for no apparent reason, the website when down.  Navigating to its URL would result in this error message:

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

What I looked up said probably the password for the account is expired.  So we tried resetting it and then setting it back to what it was before, so that it still matches the settings in the site's web config.  That didn't work, so I tried adding that user to the IIS_IUSRS group in computer management.  We also tried rebooting the server.

What did finally bring the site back up was changing the app pool's identity to a built-in account.  But now I have an issue where users have the ability to create PDFs from files that they can download and that's not working.  I don't actually know for sure if the identity issue is what's causing that.  But if I point my local web config to look at Production and run it locally I can create the PDFs just fine (so it's something with the server).  This is the error for that:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot save a PDF document with no
>   pages.
>        at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.DoSave(PdfWriter writer)
>        at PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument.Save(Stream stream, Boolean closeStream)
>   ....

But the documents do in fact have pages.

So I don't know why the server will allow me to enter the custom account as the identity but then the website becomes unavailable.  And I don't know why I can generate the PDFs running locally but not in Production.

Comment: *"But the documents do in fact have pages."* - they don't have now. This probably is caused by the pdf generation process not being able to access the information the pdfs are generated from anymore.

Comment: @mkl - the code logs downloads to the database, noting who downloaded, what document type, number of pages, and start and end of download.  If a download does not finish then the finish time is 'null'. I see all these null entries where number of pages is > 0.

Comment: The code throwing the exception is `if (this.pages == null || this.pages.Count == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot save a PDF document with no pages.")`, so the PdfSharp `PdfDocument` that threw this exception indeed had no pages. Why it had no pages, though, may be the interesting part to determine. Probably there were pages which have been removed before saving. Probably the pages were generated in a different `PdfDocument` object.  Probably ... Which ever might be the cause, the `PdfDocument` that throws the exception is page-less.